# Upgrade using downloaded $40 to Win8 x64 to blank SSD using only retail 32Bit XP install CD

Tags: windows-8, upgrade

I have purchased the downloadable $40 UPGRADE version of Windows 8.

I want to install this upgrade to a new/blank SSD drive WITHOUT prior installation of retail version of XP/service pack 3 (preferred).

I have the retail purchased 32Bit XP installation media and I also have a slipstreamed disc that contains service pack 2.  This 32bit XP license was installed to a desktop PC that I have NOT used for years (its broke).

Questions:

Can I upgrade using the $40 download upgrade version from retail 32Bit XP to 64Bit Windows 8 directly to new SSD? without first installing 32bit XP to new SSD? If 32bit XP needs to be installed to perform the upgrade to 64bit Win 8 is service XP service pack 3 still available; likewise, if the boxed retail version of XP 32bit is required to be pre-installed to the new SSD before attempting the downoladed $40 upgrade to 64Bit Win, can a clean install be performed or is a undesired actual upgrade performed?

From what I have read this is way to complicated.  Ideally, I should be able to install $40 upgrade version Win 64bit directly to new/blank SSD, then during the license verification process enter both the Win8 64Bit upgrade key and retail XP 32bit key (over internet or phone call).

Answer (score 0):

> Install this upgrade to a new/blank SSD drive WITHOUT prior
>   installation of retail version of XP/service pack 3 (prefered).

You are not allowed to do this per the license.  The license you purchase will require the Windows XP installation.

> I have the retail purchased 32Bit XP installation media and I also
>   have a slipstreamed disc that contains service pack 2. This 32bit XP
>   license was installed to a desktop PC that I have NOT used for years
>   (its broke).

If its an OEM license you won't be able to migrate it to the machine you want to install Windows 8 on.

> Can I upgrade using the $40 download upgrade version from retail 32Bit
>   XP to 64Bit Windows 8 directly to new SSD? without first installing
>   32bit XP to new SSD?

Legally, no

> If 32bit XP needs to be installed to perform the upgrade to 64bit Win
>   8 is service XP service pack 3 still available; likewise, if the boxed
>   retail version of XP 32bit is required to be pre-installed to the new
>   SSD before attempting the downoladed $40 upgrade to 64Bit Win, can a
>   clean install be performed or is a undesired actual upgrade performed?

You need to install the license, then select "Clean Install", that is all thats required to install Windows 8 x64.

> From what I have read this is way to complicated. Ideally, I should be
>   able to install $40 upgrade version Win 64bit directly to new/blank
>   SSD, then during the license verification process enter both the Win8
>   64Bit upgrade key and retail XP 32bit key (over internet or phone
>   call).

Its not complicate at all, you just brought the wrong product, the System Builder OEM license is what you wanted to purchase.